# Amazon EC2 VM Image Import Stuck on Booting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Need help!
I'm trying to import a Linux Image (RHEL 6.4) to EC2 but it is stucked on "booting" status. The interface is already set to DHCP.

```
{
    "Status": "active",
    "LicenseType": "BYOL",
    "Description": "ACS 5.7 OVA",
    "Platform": "Linux",
    "Architecture": "x86_64",
    "Progress": "59",
    "SnapshotDetails": [
        {
            "UserBucket": {
                "S3Bucket": "regus-s3-bucket",
                "S3Key": "regus-acs57.ova"
            },
            "DiskImageSize": 5237209088.0,
            "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "Format": "VMDK"
        }
    ],
    "StatusMessage": "booting",
    "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-fh6miv1p"
},
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you review http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html to maue sure all prerequisites have been met?

Comment: Yes, I've reviewed it.

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the system log of the new instance. Its not realtime but it should be available shortly after boot.

Comment: Instance is not launched yet. This is just the import process as an image. Can the logs still be seen? Thanks!

Comment: I am having same issue now with ubuntu image, did you fix that issue?